# flask-sqlalchemy dynamically construct query

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an input json like the following:

```
{
  "page": 2,
  "limit": 10,
  "order": [
    {
      "field": "id",
      "type": "asc"
    },
    {
      "field": "email",
      "type": "desc"
    },
    ...
    {
      "field": "fieldN",
      "type": "desc"
    }
  ],
  "filter": [
      {
        "field": "company_id",
        "type": "=",
        "value": 1
      },
      ...
      {
        "field": "counter",
        "type": ">",
        "value": 5             
      }
  ]
}
```

How do I dynamically construct sqlalchemy query based on my input json if I don't know fields count?

Something like this:

```
User.query.filter(filter.field, filter.type, filter.value).filter(filter.field1, filter.type1, filter.value1)...filter(filter.fieldN, filter.typeN, filter.valueN).order_by("id", "ask").order_by("email", "desc").order_by("x1", "y1")....order_by("fieldN"...."desc").all()
```

Comment: Convert it into dict and get the value using key?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the json into a dictionary and retrieve the value.

If your json is in a file (say, `data.json`), the json library will satisfy your needs:

```
import json

f = open("data.json")
data = json.load(f)
f.close()
User.query.filter(company_id=1).order_by(data["id"], data["ask"]).order_by(data["email"], data["desc"]).all()
```

If your json is a string (say, `json_data`):

```
import json

data = json.loads(json_data)
User.query.filter(company_id=1).order_by(data["id"], data["ask"]).order_by(data["email"], data["desc"]).all()
```

If your json is a request from the python requests library i.e. `res = requests.get(...)`, then `res.json()` will return a dictionary:

```
data = res.json()
User.query.filter(company_id=1).order_by(data["id"], data["ask"]).order_by(data["email"], data["desc"]).all()
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! And if a have unknown fields count, for example 3 'order' and 2 'filter'? Json is from `requests.get(...)`. Or have no field 'order' and 3 'filter'?